# Black backcolor in Controls when it was set to transparent

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, elementhost, backcolor

I´m having an issue with WPF elementHost backcolors. I have a winform that loads in a panel an UserControl(Winform). In that user control I have two panels, inside of each of them, there is an elementHost that hosts a WPF usercontrol.

The picture can be more helpful:
[image]

As you can see, the backcolor of each of them is BLACK while the element should be displayed like this:

[image]

I notice that this happened when I load other UserControls in panels. I need to know how to fix this.

Each elementHost has its backcolor set to Transparent and BackColorTransparent in True.
Also, I tried to change the backcolor in runtime, but still the same problem.

**UPDATE:**
Ok guys, I notice that if I load the UserControl in the panel in the event Load of the Form, the elementHost loads correctly. But, if I load the UserControl in the panel in a button click event, I´m getting that black backcolor.

WORKS:

```
private void frm_Configuracion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*ABM.frm_ABM_Banco_Sucursal banco_sucursal = new ABM.frm_ABM_Banco_Sucursal();
        panel1.Controls.Add(banco_sucursal);*/
    }
```

DONT WORK:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ABM.frm_ABM_Banco_Sucursal banco_sucursal = new ABM.frm_ABM_Banco_Sucursal();
        panel1.Controls.Add(banco_sucursal);
    }
```

Obviously, using the Load event would be the solution just if I´m using one UserControl, but I´m not.

Comment: [Apparently](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1ab1d4de-19b5-4342-9c8f-1f82a13f0ca5/) that is not possible. By the way, esa grilla es de winforms?

Comment: Yes I read that URL, but it´s possible. The WPF user controls are transparent in all my forms. That error just shows up when I load a Winform UserControl in a panel, and that UserControl has those ElementsHost. And yes, I did that grid in Winforms

Comment: Congrats =). I didn't think winforms was capable of such good a looking thing.

Comment: Thanks. It´s more costumizable than people know.. has it limitations, but many things can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is how I solve it:

I put this code in the Load() event of every UserControl:

```
elementHost.BackColorTransparent = true;
```

Being elementHost every elementHost element that is having that trouble.

Its curious, but that property was set in true in design time using the visual designer, I think something could mess it up during execution.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue whereby my User Controls goes black when I click on a button to update my UI.

My User Controls were found in a TableLayoutPanel which does not contain the Property **BackColorTransparent**

In order to fix my issue, I have **Refresh** the Control. A code snippet is shown below:

```
foreach (Control subControls in this.MainTableLayoutPanel.Controls)
{
    foreach (Control control in subControls.Controls)
    {
        control.Refresh();
    }
}
```